# Use previous value from Observable in map function

Tags: rxjs, observable

I have a stream of image lists resulting from an event, like this:

```
const imageSrcs$ = Rx.Observable.fromEvent($('#clicker'), 'click')
  .flatMap(() => this.imageService.getImagesForUser(userUid))
  .scan((acc, cur) => acc.concat(cur), [])
  .startWith([]);
```

`imageService.getImagesForUser(userId)`  retrieves a limited amount of images from the database and returns a list of images:

```
[
   {
       id: number,
       timestamp: string,
       ...
    },...
]
```

So this observable just takes that result and applies the accumulator (`scan()`) over it. However, `getImagesForUser` also takes an extra parameter `startAt` which is the timestamp to start the retrieval at. For my case, this should be the timestamp of the last image in the array returned by the observable.

I could, of course, do something like this:

```
lastTimestamp;
...
const imageSrcs$ = Rx.Observable.fromEvent($('#clicker'), 'click')
  .flatMap(() => this.imageService.getImagesForUser(userUid, this.lastTimestamp))
  .scan((acc, cur) => acc.concat(cur), [])
  .startWith([])
  .subscribe(list => this.lastTimestamp = list[list.length - 1].timestamp);
```

But this doesn't really seem like separation of concerns and I'm interested to know if I can just do this in one observable. I would think something like this would work:

```
const imageSrcs$ = Rx.Observable.fromEvent($('#clicker'), 'click')
  .startWith([])
  .filter(val => Array.isArray(val))
  .last()
  .map(val => val[val.length - 1].timestamp)
  .flatMap(startAt => this.imageService.getImagesForUser(userUid, startAt))
  .scan((acc, cur) => acc.concat(cur), []);
```

But of course, it doesn't because the click events are filtered out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way I can think of is like this (this just simulates your use-case but I think you'll get the point):

```
function getImagesForUser(startAt) {
  return Observable
    .range(startAt * 5, 5)
    .toArray();
}

const imageSrcs$ = Observable.defer(() => {
    let startAt = 0;
    return Observable.timer(0, 1000)
      .flatMap(() => getImagesForUser(startAt))
      .do(arr => startAt = arr[arr.length - 1]);
  })
  .scan((acc, cur) => acc.concat(cur), [])
  .startWith([])
  .subscribe(console.log);
```

Eventually the `scan()` operator could go inside the `.defer()` callbacks as well.

Just instead of clicks I'm using `Observable.timer(0, 1000)`. I don't know if there's any better way to do this without using any state variables outside the Observable chain.

Comment: Yes, I guess this is the best way. I was hoping for something without side effects with do's but oh well

Comment: Well, the `startAt` is wrapped inside the `Observable.defer` closure so at least it's not leaking.